# How to convert JSON to EDN in Clojure?

Tags: json, clojure, type-conversion, edn

I think this is a simple question but as a beginner in Clojure, I would like to convert a simple JSON to EDN in Clojure.

My JSON:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Metadata": {
                "Series": "1/2"
            },
            "Hybrid": {
                "Foo": 76308,
                "Bar": "76308",
                "Cat": "Foo123"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Footer": {
        "Count": 3,
        "Age": 0
    }
}
```

So if we assume that **data** is the json above, I have tried to convert it to an EDN using Cheshire like so:

```
(log/info "data" (cheshire.core/parse-string {(data) true}))
```

However, whenever I run this bit of code, I get the error message:

```
ERROR compojure.api.exception - clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I think I am getting this because my JSON is not a string, but unsure if I first need to convert it to a string, and **then** converting to EDN - or if there is a way I can go straight from JSON to EDN?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: If you state, that "data" is the JSON above, then you most likely mean the string.  Or if not, you are referring to the already deserialized data - in any case, you most likely don't want to call data - parens in clojure are never for fun.  using the result of data then as key to the map looks odd too.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error for this line:

```
(cheshire.core/parse-string {(data) true})
```

What is happening here:

1. Whatever your data is, it seems to be call-able - or else `(data)`
   would already fail.  E.g. with `("{}")` will give you an `class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn` error.
   Also it's unlikely, that `data` is already the de-serialized map, as
   maps are functions, but have an arity of at least one.  So we have
   to assume, that `data` is actually a function and returns whatever.
2. Next this result of this call is put into a new map, as key and the
   value `true` (`{? true}`).
3. Then this map is passed to cheshire's `parse-string`, but this
   clearly is no string, but a map, hence the error.

Given all that, and assuming, that `(data)` returns a `String`, your
best bet is:

```
(cheshire.core/parse-string (data))
```

And if you really want the EDN for that, that would be:

```
(pr-str (cheshire.core/parse-string (data)))
```

Comment: Note that `pr-str` will limit its output based on the value of `*print-length*` and maybe other dynamically bound variables too. So if you have long sequences, you may end up with corrupted edn output.

Comment: @Rulle is right. not only `*print-length*` but also some more. I guess `(defn edn-str [data]
  (binding [*print-meta* false *print-level* nil *print-namespace-maps* false *print-length* nil *print-readably* true *print-dup* false] (pr-str data)))` should be enough to avoid problems

Answer (score 0):

This will help to clarify what is occurring.  We start off by including a helpful library:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.string :as str]
    ))
```

In order to avoid the ambiguity of double-quotes for both a literal string and embedded inside of the string, we write the source JSON using single quotes, then use a helper function `str/quotes->double` to convert every single-quote in the string into a double-quote.  Otherwise, we could have read in the source JSON from a file (instead of having it inline).

```
(def json-str
  (str/quotes->double
    "{
      'Data': [
               {
                'Metadata': {
                             'Series': '1/2'
                            },
                'Hybrid': {
                           'Foo': 76308,
                           'Bar': '76308',
                           'Cat': 'Foo123'
                          }
               }
              ],
      'Footer': {
                 'Count': 3,
                 'Age': 0
                }
     } "))
```

We first convert the json **string** into an EDN **data structure** (not a string).  We then convert the EDN data struction into an **EDN string**.   The output (both `println` and `prn`) illustrate the differences:

```
(dotest
  (let [edn-data (t/json->edn json-str) ; JSON string => EDN data
        edn-str  (pr-str edn-data) ; EDN data => EDN string
        ]
    (newline)
    (println "edn-data =>")
    (spy-pretty edn-data)     ; uses 'prn'

    (newline)
    (println "edn-str (println) =>")
    (println edn-str)

    (newline)
    (println "edn-str (prn) =>")
    (prn edn-str)))
```

with result:

```
------------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 14.0.1
------------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

edn-data =>
{:Data
 [{:Metadata {:Series "1/2"},
   :Hybrid {:Foo 76308, :Bar "76308", :Cat "Foo123"}}],
 :Footer {:Count 3, :Age 0}}

edn-str (println) =>
{:Data [{:Metadata {:Series "1/2"}, :Hybrid {:Foo 76308, :Bar "76308", :Cat "Foo123"}}], :Footer {:Count 3, :Age 0}}

edn-str (prn) =>
"{:Data [{:Metadata {:Series \"1/2\"}, :Hybrid {:Foo 76308, :Bar \"76308\", :Cat \"Foo123\"}}], :Footer {:Count 3, :Age 0}}"
```

Think carefully about what is a data structure and what is a string.  If we write `[1 :b "hi"]` in a Clojure source file, the Clojure Reader creates a data structure that is a 3-element vector containg an int, a keyword, and a string.  If we convert that into a string using `str`, the output is just a string of 11 characters and is not a data structure.

However, if we want to paste that string (inside of double-quotes) into our source file, we need not only the outer double-quotes to mark the beginning and end of the string, but each double-quote inside the string (e.g. as part of the `"hi"`) needs to be escaped, so the Clojure Reader can tell that they belong inside of the string and don't mark the beginning or end of a string.

It takes a while to get used to all of the different modes!

---

### Clojure Reader vs Compiler

Clojure source code files are processed in 2 passes.

1. The Clojure Reader takes the text of each source file (a giant string of many lines) and converts it into a data structure.
2. The Clojure Compiler takes the data structure from (1) and outputs Java bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing the variable data as a clojure Map and not as a String (or a json object).

Thats actually what the error says as well.

cheshire.core/parse-string expects a json object which will be a string.

```
'{ "name": "Cheshire", "needs": "a string"}'
```